# choosing time and AM or PM

Tags: php

i have an option value for time in main form and another option for am or pm...now what confuses me is how am i going to code it when if example i choese 1 and then pm...how am i goin to call it on the database?i also have to filter the sales reports by time and by pm.. hope someone can help me..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set AM/PM through capital A or lowercase a depending on your preference of capital AM/PM or lowercase am/pm. As far as your question on how to interact with the database, your time inserted should be unedited, IE you don't want to apply the styling from the date function and insert that into your database as a string because that will prevent you from changing it in the future. Instead create a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column in your table, and put the date in that, then when you select from the table you can apply styling to fit your needs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

### From Database to Display

The PHP Function `[date()][1]` can be used to convert a Unix Timestamp into a Human-Readable form.

```
<?php
// $time is assumed as a Timestamp from DB or other
echo date( 'g:i:sa, l jS F Y' , $time );
?>
Will Return
3:43pm, Wednesday 25th August 2010
```

Alternately, you could use the `[strftime()][2]` which performs a similar role, but has different placeholders (it also lacks the placeholder for "st","nd","th" after the day number). The benefit of this function is that you could include plain text within the format, as all placeholders are prefixed with "%" - so "hello" would not be treated as a placeholder.

```
<?php
// $time is assumed as a Timestamp from DB or other
echo strftime( '%l:%M:$S%P, %A %e %B %Y' , $time );
?>
Will Return
3:43pm, Wednesday 25 August 2010
```

### Translating User-Entered Data into a Format for the Database

Most databases I have worked with have been pretty intelligent about how they handle timestamps. All you should need to do is, if there are more than one field being used (ie one for hour, one for minutes, one for am/pm), join them together into a single string, and just make sure that the resulting string is of a format able to be parsed by PHP.

The function `strtotime()` can turn a Human-readable time into a Unix Timestamp, which your database should be able to handle without any problems.

```
<?php
// $input is the string (joined or solo) containing the Human-readable timestamp
$input = "2010/08/25 3:43pm";
if( ( $out = strtotime( $input ) )===false ){
  echo 'Timestamp "'.$input.'" Unrecognisable';
}else{
  echo $out;
}
?>
Will Return
1282743780
```

If the string being parsed is not recognisable according to the [PHP Date Time Formats](http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), then it will return false.